# Installing redis module in python3 instead of python 2

Tags: python, redis, server, virtualenv

I installed redis server on ubuntu 16.04 and now it's module is installed in python 2 but I need it in python 3. I did everything I could with the info from googling. Can you help me to install it in python 3?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the guide for creating [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this will help users better answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip3 install redis
```

Assuming the `pip` for Python 3 is called `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an environment manager. Either [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). That way you can switch between python versions and use the same package manager to install packages in different distributions. I prefer to use Anaconda. [Here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) is the documentation for managing environments with conda. It should help you get started.